# dataTable not display ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need your helps guys. to correct what's wrong with the code.

I want to copy the row table on `table1` into `table2`, but the data does not show up when I use ajax json. have to insert manually into html.

1. [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/o6ysgzps/)
2. I want to copy the row table on datatable, but the data does not show up when I use ajax json.

**Code Snippet Demonstration**

```js
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stockTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zvujb",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "className": 'dt-body-center',

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "select": {
      "style": "multi"
    },
    "order": [
      [4, "desc"]
    ],
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,

    }); // first table 
    
 var catalogTable = $('#table2').dataTable(); // Second table 
   
    stockTable.on('click', 'tbody tr' ,function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
 catalogTable.on('click', 'tbody tr' ,function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
 
 $('#LeftMove').on('click',function () {
  moveRows(catalogTable, stockTable);
 });
 
 $('#RightMove').on('click',function () {
  moveRows(stockTable, catalogTable);
 });
 
});
 
function moveRows(fromTable, toTable){
 var $row= fromTable.find(".selected");
 $.each($row, function(k, v){
  if(this !== null){
   addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
   toTable.fnAddData(addRow);
   fromTable.fnDeleteRow(this);
  }
 });
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#table2_wrapper{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:50px;
}
#table1_wrapper{
 
 margin-left:50px;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
  background-color: #b0bed9;
}
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected > .sorting_1 {
background-color: #a6b3cd;
}
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected > .sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected > .sorting_1 {
background-color: #a1aec7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
      
  <div class="one" style="padding-bottom:50px">
  <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Audience Name</th>
             <th>Type</th>
             <th>Size</th>
             <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
</table>
</div>

<center>
<button id="RightMove" style="float:left;">right &raquo;</button>
<button id="LeftMove" style="float:left;">&laquo; left</button>
</center>

<br>
<br>

<div class="two">
<table id="table2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Audience Name</th>
             <th>Type</th>
             <th>Size</th>
             <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Problem Solved]** https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/o6ysgzps/2/

Change jquery file, using [**jquery-1.12.4.js**](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js)

and edit `table2` js code == `table1`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stockTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zvujb",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "className": 'dt-body-center',

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "select": {
      "style": "multi"
    },
    "order": [
      [4, "desc"]
    ],
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,

    }); // first table 

    var catalogTable = $('#table2').dataTable({

  "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "className": 'dt-body-center',

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "select": {
      "style": "multi"
    },
    "order": [
      [4, "desc"]
    ],
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,

    }); // Second table 

    stockTable.on('click', 'tbody tr' ,function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
    catalogTable.on('click', 'tbody tr' ,function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#LeftMove').on('click',function () {
        moveRows(catalogTable, stockTable);
    });

    $('#RightMove').on('click',function () {
        moveRows(stockTable, catalogTable);
    });

});

function moveRows(fromTable, toTable){
    var $row= fromTable.find(".selected");
    $.each($row, function(k, v){
        if(this !== null){
            addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
            toTable.fnAddData(addRow);
            fromTable.fnDeleteRow(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ajax call as follows

```
 ajax: {
         "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zvujb",
         "type": "GET",
         "error": function (e) {
                },
         "dataSrc": function (d) {
                    return d
                }
        },
```

Comment: @CalvinAnanda following is link to my project take a look at it https://github.com/NisalSP9/ABSD-Final-Project/blob/master/build/web/components/senior_citizenship_ID/senior_citizenship_ID.js